# Setting up SASS, Compass and Sage (Wordpress) on PC to Work Remotely

Tags: wordpress, sass, wordpress-theming, compass-sass, roots-sage

I went through the basic installation of a test sass file and was able to make changes and Compass compiled the CSS.

I initially started with Bones, but am now switching to Sage. For starting with Sage, I do not know how to tell Compass to watch the scss to overwrite the css file and then to upload the changes to the server. I am fairly new to the command prompt and am trying to learn how to create this development environment.

I've seen some developers using Grunt, Uglify, etc. but all of this is confusing and very new to me and I am a very visual person. I need to see someone do the task to remember how to do it, YouTube helps, but it would be nice to have explanations also of what does what and why.

Comment: I don't think you need Compass. Sage 8.x is set up with gulp. Once your development environment is set up (node, gulp and Bower globally), you just run `npm install` to install node dependencies. Then you run `gulp` from within the theme directory, and gulp will compile all assets. If you're serious about Sage, you should buy "Theme Development with Sage" by Ben Word - well worth the asking price.

Comment: Would you be able to assist me remotely on troubleshooting it? I feel close, but am still a little lost..

Comment: Hi, go through these instructions step by step: https://roots.io/sage/docs/theme-development-and-building/ if you get stuck, amend your question with your specific problems and I'll try to help. Note that https://discourse.roots.io/ is a great place to find out about Sage.